# utl_file_dir paramete is null. Unable to use utl_file

Tags: oracle

I wanted to use utl_file package for reading file and uploading them into db.

```
       declare
           l_fhandle utl_file.file_type;
           l_clob    CLOB;
           l_buffer  VARCHAR2(4096);
     BEGIN
     l_fhandle := utl_file.fopen('admin',
                          'FILE.TXT',
                          'R');
     dbms_lob.createtemporary(l_clob, TRUE, DBMS_LOB.CALL);
     LOOP
     BEGIN
      utl_file.get_line(L_FHANDLE, l_buffer);
      dbms_output.put_line(l_buffer);
      dbms_lob.writeappend(l_clob, length(l_buffer), l_buffer);

      EXCEPTION
      WHEN no_data_found THEN
    INSERT INTO interfacetable
      (FILENAME, content)
    VALUES
      ('FILE', l_clob);
    EXIT;

        END;
     END LOOP;
   END;
  /
```

Created directory using sql

```
create or replace directory admin as 'D:\temp';
```

But getting error when run the procedure

> declare
>   * ERROR at line 1: ORA-29280: invalid directory path ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 41 ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 478
>   ORA-06512: at line 6

Please help

Comment: Change your directory name to UPPERCASE

Answer (score 0):

You may have two cases then :

- Try upper case letters for the directory name

> i.e. instead of `admin` use `ADMIN`

- Be sure that the OS level user has permission to write to a folder

> ```
>  create or replace directory ADMIN as 'D:\temp';   /   
>  grant read, write on directory ADMIN to {user | role | PUBLIC};   /
> ```